# OpenCV python output bounding rectangle X coordinates to object

Tags: python, opencv

I need to create an object with the value of the bounding rectangle X coordinates that is tracking movement. Using Python in OpenCV. Does anyone know of a way I can do this?
I will use that object to calculate servo values for a laser tracker.

```
import cv2

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret1,frame1= cap.read()

gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray1, (21, 21), 0)
cv2.imshow('window',frame1)

while(True):
    ret2,frame2=cap.read()
    gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray2, (21, 21), 0)

    deltaframe=cv2.absdiff(gray1,gray2)
    frame_flip2 = cv2.flip(deltaframe, -1)
    #cv2.imshow('delta',frame_flip2)
    threshold = cv2.threshold(deltaframe, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    threshold = cv2.dilate(threshold,None)
    #cv2.imshow('threshold',threshold)
    _,countour,heirarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for i in countour:
        if cv2.contourArea(i) < 600:
            continue

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(i)
        cv2.rectangle(frame2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    frame_flip = cv2.flip(frame2, -1)
    cv2.imshow('window',frame_flip)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "create an object"? You've got coordinates with `(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(i)` do you need to do something with them?

Comment: Sorry Im really new to programming. Must seem so stupid...I am calculating servo value from the bounding rectangle x coordinate. In this example I have a random figure of 535 but I need it to read from bounding rectangle X coordinate..................... pixel_x = 535...................                                                                            
servo_value = int(0.15*(639.-pixel_x)+262.)

Comment: what is `pixel_x`, what are the other values in the `servo_value` calculation, e.g. `639` or `262`? I don't know what this servo value calculation is, but, you've got the corners of the rectangle which is I assume what you need.

Comment: pixel_x must be equal to the bounding rectangle X coordinate. How do I write that?

Comment: `(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(i)` gives you the `x`, the `y`, and the width (`w`) and height (`h`). So, `pixel_x = x` below the `boundingRect(i)` line.

Comment: I owe you a beer...I did that before but it never worked because it was not below the boundingRect(i) line.....A million thank yous

Comment: :) computer reads top to bottom (at least within a single function) and before this line `(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(i)` it doesn't even know what `x` is.